# How to create relational articles using Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I am required to use Joomla for a project which essentially consists of several 'Categories' which contain articles that consist of text, images and videos.

I want the images and videos to behave like 'Articles' in 'Categories' as I want to be able to list them individual aside from residing within text based articles. How would I link several video and image 'Articles' to another 'Category' of 'Articles'?

**So for example**, I have 'News', 'Video' and 'Image' categories. I want to be able to create a 'News' Article and then several 'Image's and 'Video's to that Article.

Comment: Sorry but after reading your post 4 times, i don't understand what you need!

Comment: Not sure but I'm afraid it may be difficult without a third-party extension. Check out K2 and FJ.

Comment: Thanks, I think essentially what I am asking is: "Is it possible to have 'many-to-many' relationships between Categories". Which it seems like it isn't. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FJ Related may be a key to helping you here.  It's a great tool that allows you to categorize articles together based on keywords.

I'm not sure of way to insert them into the same article on one page, but it would allow you to have 'related videos' and 'related images' very easily by simply adding the same keywords to them.  FJ Related also allows for 'random selection' of those articles, images and videos so that every time they view the page the 'related' items will be different, but still related.

I've used it in a number of instances to successfully pull of something that sounds similar to what you desire.  Good luck!